# Delphi DX10 print to XPS without dialog

Tags: delphi, printing, xps

**I'm using unit Tprinters not TDocInfo**

I want to print to a XPS file with a predifined filename. How can I prevent the "saveAs" popup dialog, please ?

```
printer.setPrinter('Microsoft XPS Document Writer','','',0);
// I want something like : printer.fileName := 'myXPS.xps';
printer.BeginDoc; // here pops up the "saveAs" dialog but I don't it as I know the filename
.........
printer.endDoc;
```

Comment: Show us the code that you currently use.

Comment: Have you tried [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41748116/how-to-set-filename-when-printing-to-microsoft-print-to-pdf-in-delphi)?

Comment: I already have write a printing unit that works fine and i use it with other applications. This unit uses printers but the example you show me uses a different approach.

My question remains : Is there a way to set the output filename using printers unit or not ?

Comment: According to [How to Programmatically Print XPS Files](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa969772(v=vs.100).aspx), this can be done using the AddJob function. There's a C#/VB.Net sample, but unfortunately they use the .Net PrintQueue class to demonstrate. To use TPrinter, you may be able to do the same thing yourself using the raw API version of [AddJob](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd183329(v=vs.85).aspx). I'll see if at some point today I can dig up an example of doing so.

Comment: It looks like AddJob() from the raw API has been deprecated since Win8's release, so it's probably not going to work for you either.